# Pandas NLTK tokenizing "unhashable type: 'list'"

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

Following this example: [Twitter data mining with Python and Gephi: Case synthetic biology](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/twitter-data-mining-python-gephi-case-synthetic-biology-mikko-dufva)

`CSV to: df['Country', 'Responses']`

```
'Country'
Italy
Italy
France
Germany

'Responses' 
"Loren ipsum..."
"Loren ipsum..."
"Loren ipsum..."
"Loren ipsum..."
```

1. tokenize the text in 'Responses'
2. remove the 100 most common words (based on brown.corpus)
3. identify the remaining 100 most frequent words

I can get through step 1 and 2, but get an error on step 3:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I believe it's because I'm working in a dataframe and have made this (likely erronous) modification:

Original example:

```
#divide to words
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
words = tokenizer.tokenize(tweets)
```

My code:

```
#divide to words
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
df['tokenized_sents'] = df['Responses'].apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
```

My full code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('CountryResponses.csv', encoding='utf-8', skiprows=0, error_bad_lines=False)

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
df['tokenized_sents'] = df['Responses'].apply(nltk.word_tokenize)

words =  df['tokenized_sents']

#remove 100 most common words based on Brown corpus
fdist = FreqDist(brown.words())
mostcommon = fdist.most_common(100)
mclist = []
for i in range(len(mostcommon)):
    mclist.append(mostcommon[i][0])
words = [w for w in words if w not in mclist]

Out: ['the',
 ',',
 '.',
 'of',
 'and',
...]

#keep only most common words
fdist = FreqDist(words)
mostcommon = fdist.most_common(100)
mclist = []
for i in range(len(mostcommon)):
    mclist.append(mostcommon[i][0])
words = [w for w in words if w not in mclist]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

There are many questions on unhashable lists, but none that I understand to be quite the same.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

---

TRACEBACK

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-164-a0d17b850b10> in <module>()
  1 #keep only most common words
----> 2 fdist = FreqDist(words)
  3 mostcommon = fdist.most_common(100)
  4 mclist = []
  5 for i in range(len(mostcommon)):

/home/*******/anaconda3/envs/*******/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/probability.py in __init__(self, samples)
    104         :type samples: Sequence
    105         """
--> 106         Counter.__init__(self, samples)
    107 
    108     def N(self):

/home/******/anaconda3/envs/******/lib/python3.5/collections/__init__.py in __init__(*args, **kwds)
    521             raise TypeError('expected at most 1 arguments, got %d' % len(args))
    522         super(Counter, self).__init__()
--> 523         self.update(*args, **kwds)
    524 
    525     def __missing__(self, key):

/home/******/anaconda3/envs/******/lib/python3.5/collections/__init__.py in update(*args, **kwds)
    608                     super(Counter, self).update(iterable) # fast path when counter is empty
    609             else:
--> 610                 _count_elements(self, iterable)
    611         if kwds:
    612             self.update(kwds)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: what is the type of element in words

Comment: They're strings (English sentences)

Comment: could you print out and check. It seems you have list in it

Comment: Note that the line `words = [w for w in words if w not in mclist]` should not be inside the for loop.

Comment: words is showing as a list: `type(words) = list`

Comment: I'm assuming at this point that the original article wasn't using a dataframe and that's where the extra complication is coming from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FreqDist` function takes in an iterable of hashable objects (made to be strings, but it probably works with whatever).  The error you're getting is because you pass in an iterable of lists.  As you suggested, this is because of the change you made:

```
df['tokenized_sents'] = df['Responses'].apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
```

If I understand the [Pandas apply function documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) correctly, that line is applying the `nltk.word_tokenize` function to some series.  `word-tokenize` returns a list of words.

As a solution, simply add the lists together before trying to apply `FreqDist`, like so:

```
allWords = []
for wordList in words:
    allWords += wordList
FreqDist(allWords)
```

A more complete revision to do what you would like.  If all you need is to identify the second set of 100, note that `mclist` will have that the second time.

```
df = pd.read_csv('CountryResponses.csv', encoding='utf-8', skiprows=0, error_bad_lines=False)

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
df['tokenized_sents'] = df['Responses'].apply(nltk.word_tokenize)

lists =  df['tokenized_sents']
words = []
for wordList in lists:
    words += wordList

#remove 100 most common words based on Brown corpus
fdist = FreqDist(brown.words())
mostcommon = fdist.most_common(100)
mclist = []
for i in range(len(mostcommon)):
    mclist.append(mostcommon[i][0])
words = [w for w in words if w not in mclist]

Out: ['the',
 ',',
 '.',
 'of',
 'and',
...]

#keep only most common words
fdist = FreqDist(words)
mostcommon = fdist.most_common(100)
mclist = []
for i in range(len(mostcommon)):
    mclist.append(mostcommon[i][0])
# mclist contains second-most common set of 100 words
words = [w for w in words if w in mclist]
# this will keep ALL occurrences of the words in mclist
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot. I wonder thou if this will allow me to eliminate the 100 most common 100 English words, and then identify the 100 most frequent in the texts? I'll try it out...

Comment: Yes, it's not making a `set` out of the words, just putting them all in one list.  so it's easy enough, then, to use your list comprehension `words = [w for w in words if w not in most_common_english_words]` and then the `most_common` function as you have.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding the lists together but got a null set: `words [ ]`. My understanding is that the first function removes the most common words according to Brown, returning the remaining words to the second function to again identify the 100 most common words, but this time keeping them putting into `mclist[]`. I'll keep trying...

Comment: I did try `words = df['Responses'].apply(nltk.word_tokenize)` but after a long time, e.g. 20mins, it returned no data.

Comment: `itertools` from the other question you mentioned might be another approach.

Comment: if `words = df['Responses'].apply()` took so long, why did putting the result in a dictionary work?

Comment: I don't know (yet). Still trying to figure out the underlying logic, particularly, what changes between the 1st function (which works) and the second (which breaks).

Comment: There are few things in life as good as waking up to a fully working solution on Stackoverflow! Thank you for taking the time to solve this. I now have my Top 100 words. This is going to get used a lot in the future. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.